# Appending Keypair in Stringbuilder. AddIfNotNull Method

Tags: c#, dictionary

Hi I have the method below. It simply checks if the keypair value is null however getting error: `Cannot convert TValue to TKey`

```
public static class DictionaryExtension
    {
        public static void AddIfNotNull<TKey, TValue>(TKey key, TValue value)
            where TValue : class 
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                key = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to achieve below without wrapping all my properties in if statements.

```
 public string myObject(Root token)
    {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (token.backgroundColor != null)
        {
            sb.Append("background-color= " + token.backgroundColor);
        }
        if (token.text != null)
        {
            sb.Append("text-size= " + token.text);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
}
```

I would like to call
AddIfNotNull so for example

`AddIfNotNull(sb.Append("background-color= " + token.text));` I know this is wrong but this is what I am trying to achieve. Instead of wrapping everything in my if statement I would just like to call a method that handles null values and non existing keys

Comment: Not quite sure why you are assigning the value to the key? Do you really need a dictionary in this case?

Comment: @Milen sorry it is my first time writing an extension. I basically have JToken pairs which I convert ToObject<class> and if the value is null or key doesnt exists do not append to my string builder. Please see my updated question

Comment: Not sure if Dictionary is what you need in this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a valid extension method, you need to use the `this` keyword for the first parameter. This way C# knows which type you're extending. I guess you're trying to extend the StringBuilder type, so I'd do something like this:

```
public static class StringBuilderExtension
{
    public static void AppendIfNotNull<TValue>(this StringBuilder sb, TValue value, string prefix)
        where TValue : class 
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            sb.Append(prefix + value);
        }
    }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
sb.AppendIfNotNull(token.backgroundColor, "background-color=");
```

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for however this would only handle background-color how can pass both key and value for example   sb.Append(key + value); As there will be multiple properties

Comment: Edited the answer to accommodate what you're asking

Comment: Thanks marc that did the trick! I understand extensions more. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: How can I make it so it handles int I am getting error "The type int must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter. I could always do ToString() not sure if thats best practice

Comment: Just stick with the `.ToString()`, or add an overloaded extension method that uses `int` for the type of the value parameter.

Comment: Last question sorry, How can I amend this so if  prefix or value is null or doesnt exists dont append. I know I am passing key however it might not exists in the property list.

Comment: @Mask-dCodex Why would you need to know that, when you are sending it as and argument? It does seem that this question is different from the one already posed, maybe you should create a new question for that instead?